# SQL statements where value could be nothing (empty)

Tags: php, sql

I have some search functionality which allows a user to either select a name from a drop down list or type a persons name or part of it (wildcard functionality) into a search field.

The problem I am having is that if the drop down option is used then the search field won't be and vice versa.

I have tried some SQL as follows (please note the variables represent data sent in via a form):

```
SELECT id, name, age FROM player
    WHERE player.id = '$id'
        OR player.name LIKE '%$text%'
```

When the above is used the wildcard functionality works fine.

However if you select a player from the drop down then it returns all players.  This is because the value for `$text` is nothing (empty) and LIKE '%%' means select everything and hence it selects all names.

I then tried the following:

```
SELECT id, name, age FROM player
    WHERE player.id = '$id'
        AND player.name LIKE '%$text%'
```

Now the drop down functionality works as expected but wild card searches do not work.  This is because I assume that AND requires both statements to be true and because `$id` is nothing (empty) when just a wildcard entry is specified, the condition is never true.

Can anyone help me with some sql to ensure that both the dropdown and the wildcard search work in isolation of each other?

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: If you're generating the SQL through PHP, why not just add an if statement to check and see what parameters have been chosen, and just add the appropriate text to the WHERE clause?

Comment: I take it `$id` is passed if droppdown and `$text` if text input?

Comment: Just in case you're using `mysql_*` functions (which, by your code it looks like you are): it may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: do you getting result for this much "SELECT id, name, age FROM player
    WHERE player.id = '$id'"

Comment: @andrewsi I did originally try doing this.  So I said  if ($_GET['name'] != '') // A name is selected from the dropdown (it is the id that is passed in)
 {
  $where .= " OR id = :id";
  $placeholders[':id'] = $_GET['name'];
 }
 
 if ($_GET['text'] != '') // Some search text was specified
 {
  $where .= " AND name LIKE :text";
  $placeholders[':text'] = '%' . $_GET['text'] . '%';
 }

but it still did not work

thought there would be a simple 'sql only' way to solve this?

Comment: @matt no I am using PDO so no worries there

Comment: @anoopssGolden yes that works fine but I need them to work in harmony rather then just the dropdown by itself.

Comment: @Johnny - you're almost there, but you need to make sure that you're producing valid SQL. Your code at the moment always has an OR before the `id` parameter and an AND before the `text` one, whether they're needed or not.

Comment: then use the code $text="%".$text."%";
SELECT id, name, age FROM player
    WHERE player.id = '$id'
        OR player.name LIKE '%$text%'

Comment: comment me whether you got result or not?

Comment: @AnoopssGolden thanks for your help.  I went with Zac's solution in the end but I can see how what you've suggested would be useful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$params = ''

if($id !== ''){
  $params = "player.id = '$id'";
} else if($text !== ''){
  $params = "player.name LIKE '%$text%'";
}

$sql = "SELECT id,name,age FROM player WHERE {$params}";

mysql_query($sql);  //if using mysql_
```

Answer (score 0):

Require `id` conditionally:

```
$idCondition = "";
if ($id) {
    $idCondition = "player.id = '$id' AND ";
}

$query = "SELECT id, name, age FROM player WHERE {$idCondition}player.name LIKE '%$text%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT id, name, age FROM player
WHERE (player.id = '$id' AND '$id' <> '')
    OR (player.name LIKE '%$text%' AND '$text' <>'')"
```